# Lightning Flow Issue

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

Is it possible to create multiple screens in a flow depending on number of records received?

**Scenario:**
If in flow by querying we receive 10 records, then can we have 10 different screens for each record and in every screen we need a certain field to be editable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you simply need a loop, an sobject collection, an sobject variable, a screen, and an update sobject element.

[image: Edit Record Loop in Flow]